# Call scripts in parallel from sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to call 3 of my scripts from SQL Developer.

```
@"myscript1"
@"myscript2"
@"myscript3"
```

However, I need to call them in parallel. Is there any alternative to having to open 3 Developer sessions and running them in each?

Comment: a connection/thread/process can only do one thing at a a time. what you are wanting is to run 3 things concurrently, which require 3 connections. I would write a script that calls SQLcl, 3times, one for each script, and backgrounds the processes. SQLcl is a CLI for SQL Developer.

Comment: How could I do that? Do you have any example?

Comment: i'll try to do that tomorrow

Comment: Hi, @thatjeffsmith did you get a chance to take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows create a .bat file that launches SQLcl and runs your script, repeat as needed.

[image]

My 'run-sleep.cmd' file -

```
start c:\sqlcl\22.4\sqlcl\bin\sql hr/oracle @c:\users\jdsmith\desktop\sleep.sql
start c:\sqlcl\22.4\sqlcl\bin\sql hr/oracle @c:\users\jdsmith\desktop\sleep.sql
start c:\sqlcl\22.4\sqlcl\bin\sql hr/oracle @c:\users\jdsmith\desktop\sleep.sql
```

My 'sleep.sql' file -

```
set serveroutput on
begin
 dbms_lock.sleep(3);
 dbms_output.put_line('slept 3 seconds, goodbye');
end;
/
```

On Linux or OS X, you would create a .sh script and do the equivalent call out to the 'sql' binary (found in your SQL Developer bin directory, or available as a separate [download](https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/java/sqldeveloper/sqlcl-latest.zip).)

Calling the cmd file from OS Prompt, I get 3 new cmd windows, each running SQLcl, running the script(s), concurrently.

FYI Putting your connection password as clear text in a script file isn't recommended.

*Disclaimer: I work for Oracle and am the product manager for SQLcl.*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. When opening the sql file in the bin folder, it automatically opens https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/ What does this mean?

Comment: It means it can't find a suitable version of Oracle Java. Latest version of SQLcl is looking for java 11 or 17

Comment: I have just extracted the files from my installation of Windows x64 Compressed Archive in my C disk but it does not seem to work either. What steps am I missing/where can I find the documentation to get past this? I have tried the documentation in https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk19-doc-downloads.html but it does not seem to talk about the installation itself.

Comment: once you extract the zip you have to update the path, so java can be found. Also like i said, we support 11 or 17 (not 19, although it should probably work)

Comment: That worked. Now I am struggling with what to put in your hr/oracle part. I have tried my username/password but it says Error de E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=Dm17rrPlS0i182YV0c8Obg==)

Comment: look at your connection string in SQL Developer, replicate in SQLcl

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, where can I find that string in SQL Developer? I have connected via TNS, but not sure what the connection string looks like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250977/discussion-between-thatjeffsmith-and-javi-torre).